# Flutter || url_launcher failed to open specified url

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to launch this URL ("https://m.me/nagadhat"). but cannot launch on my app. But I can visit this URL from my browser and anywhere else.

```
  String chatURL = "https://m.me/nagadhat";
        var url = Uri.parse(chatURL);
        if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
          await launchUrl(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
```

This is the screenshot when I'm triggering the code

[image]

Comment: Please add internet permission in android manifest file

Comment: Please chage question also. its description saying different thing

Comment: @HardikMehta I already added internet permission. But same problem

Comment: add this also :       mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
 along with url inside launchUrl method

Comment: Wow! It worked after adding launch mode. Thanks!! @HardikMehta

Comment: @HardikMehta you should add that comment as an answer so it doesn't get lost if comments are purged

Answer (score 2):

Adding `LaunchMode` to `launchUrl` solved my issue.
This is the changed code.

```
 String chatURL = "https://m.me/nagadhat";
        var url = Uri.parse(chatURL);
        if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
          await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
```